# Replacing text in Bash

Tags: string, bash, replace

i have 2 variables:

```
varString = abcd
varNumber = 12345
```

I want to find the varString string in a file named `textFile.txt`.
the line will look like:

```
abcd:11111:blah:00000:blah
```

All the fields are of unknown length.

I want to find the abcd line, and change the `11111` bit to `varNumber` which is `12345` so afterwards the line on the file will be:

```
abcd:12345:blah:00000:blah
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will do:

```
sed -e "s/\($varString\):\([0-9]*\):/\1:$varNumber:/g" textFile.txt
```

It replaces a string like `$varString:<digits>:` with `$varString:$varNumber:`. Output is on `stdout`. To make an in-place edit, supply the `-i '~'` option to `sed`.

Comment: As a noob, especially to sed, i have no idea how to adapt this to my code... especially in regards to making it search within and change my text file...

Comment: Ahh, that makes more sense, but how to modify the actual file here

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F: -v OFS=: -v varString=abcd -v varNumber=12345 '{if($1==varString)$2=varNumber;print}' file
```